# Is this a good Close Votes Review Audit question?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, disputed-review-audits

I think I've changed my answer to the title question to, **yes**!

[Apple developer portal is down since more than a day, is there a way to add a device to a provisioning profile without that site?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2626628)

<strike>Although</strike> I'm happy for this to be asked and answered here, <strike>it's not *programming* related, and it's local in any case,</strike> and on re-reading it closely I see it has been worded so that it's definitely <strike>questionable</strike> not for closing.

IMHO <strike>not</strike> a good audit question.

Comment: I see phrases like "Apple Developer Portal", "XCode", and "iOS Simulator"—why is this not programming related? Remember that we do allow questions about software used by programmers. Not all questions have to have code.

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, I'm not saying that it's definitely closeable, just that it is questionable enough to _not_ be a Review Audit question.

Comment: @MarkHurd Would you consider closing it if you saw this question and weren't doing a review?  It's about a [software tool commonly used by programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in that area.

Comment: @BLaZuRE Probably no, but if it did already have close votes, I'd possibly consider it.

Comment: @BLaZuRE Your comment caused me to re-read the question closely and I saw it asked for a specific alternative irrespective of the current problem that may go away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not a good audit review question.

It's one of those edge-case questions about a company's website or service; it's a question for Apple, not us.  The posted answer is useless, only confirming what we probably already knew anyway, that no there is no other way to do it.  Why would there be?

Audit reviews should be done with unambiguous questions where the question's outcome is clearly apparent, not with questions that could be open to debate.